# Java- Get decimal at position n

Tags: java, floating-point, formatting

What is the best way to get the decimal at position n from a float (by cutting out everything from the number except that decimal)?

It should work like this:

```
getDecimal(3.654987, 4)  =>  returns 0.0009
getDecimal(3.654987, 2)  =>  returns 0.05
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Float f = new Float("0.123456789");
System.out.println(f.toString().charAt(5));
```

Prints 4. Try in this direction.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who answered, I think this is the easiest solution to implement in my particular case.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
public static double getDecimal(double num, int n) {
     return ((int) (num * Math.pow(10, (double) n)) % 10) * Math.pow(10, (double) -n); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the position will be always a positive integer(`> 0`):

```
float input = 3.654987f;
int pos = 4;
String op = String.valueOf(input).replaceAll("\\d*\\.\\d{"+(pos-1)+"}(\\d)\\d+",
             "0." + new String(new char[pos-1]).replace("\0", "0") + "$1");
System.out.println(op);
```